# 'CppObject' is not a type identifier - Cython compile error on using another CPP class as an argument

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to make a minimal C++ library to use with a Cython project, but I'm running into issues compiling a C++ class in the same namespace that uses another C++ class as an argument for a method. The first error I get with the minimal example is `Point3d.pxd:8:30: 'Vector3d' is not a type identifier`, complaining about the .pxd file for Point3d. Are there any examples of C++ classes that reference each other but are then wrapped into Cython this way? Or is my error in the definition of the class itself in C++?

Point3d.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point3d.h"
#include "Vector3d.h"

namespace geometry {

  Point3d::Point3d() {}

  Point3d::Point3d(double x, double y, double z = 0.0) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
  }

  Point3d::~Point3d() {}

  void Point3d::move_point(const Vector3d v) {
    this->x = this->x + v.x;
    this->y = this->y + v.y;
    this->z = this->z + v.z;
  }

}
```

Point3d.h

```
#ifndef POINT3D_H
#define POINT3D_H
#include "Vector3d.h"

namespace geometry {
  class Point3d {
  public:
    double x, y, z;
    Point3d();
    Point3d(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Point3d();
    void move_point(const Vector3d v);
   };
}

#endif
```

Point3d.pxd

```
cdef extern from "Point3d.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "Point3d.h" namespace "geometry":
    cdef cppclass Point3d nogil:
        double x, y, z
        Point3d() except +
        void move_point(const Vector3d v)
```

Vector3d.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector3d.h"

namespace geometry {

  Vector3d::Vector3d() {}

  Vector3d::Vector3d(double x, double y, double z = 0.0) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
  }

  Vector3d::~Vector3d() {}


}
```

Vector3d.h

```
#ifndef VECTOR3D_H
#define VECTOR3D_H

namespace geometry {
  class Vector3d {
  public:
    double x, y, z;
    Vector3d();
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Vector3d();
  };
}

#endif
```

Vector3d.pxd

```
cdef extern from "Vector3d.cpp":
    pass

cdef extern from "Vector3d.h" namespace "geometry":
    cdef cppclass Vector3d nogil:
        double x, y, z
        Vector3d() except +
        Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) except +
```

testPoint.pxd

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from pointTest.geometry cimport Point3d

cdef class testPoint(object):
    cdef vector[Point3d] *test_pt
```

testPoint.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++

from Vector3d cimport Vector3d
from Point3d cimport Point3d
from libc.stdlib cimport free
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef class TestPoint(object):

    def __cinit__(TestPoint self):
        self.test_pt = new vector[Point3d]()

    def __init__(TestPoint self, list pt):

        # initialize vectors
        self.test_pt.push_back(Point3d(pt[0],
                                       pt[1],
                                       pt[2]))
    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self.anchor_pt != NULL:
            free(self.anchor_pt)

    cpdef move_pt(TestPoint self):
        pt = self.test_pt[0].at(0)
        pt.move_pt(Vector3d(1, 1, 1))
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext = Extension("testPoint",
            sources=["testPoint.pyx", "Point3d.cpp", "Vector3d.cpp"],
            language="c++")

setup(name="testPoint", ext_modules=cythonize(ext))
```

Comment: If you need definitions from Point3d.pxd in Vector3d.pxd, you should cimport - the same way you use `from Point3d cimport Point3d` in the pyx-file.

Comment: Furthermore, if you don't know what `cdef extern from "Point3d.cpp": pass` does exactly - just drop it.

Comment: First comment fixed the 'not a type identifier' error, but removing the pass statement caused a `Symbol not found` error on Point3d. Code runs as expected with the cdef extern statement included.